# RhodeCode proxied by IIS 7

Tags: iis-7

I installed RhodeCode 1.2.2 at a Windows 2008R2 (64Bit) box.

I had setup a IIS 7 as a Proxy Server (Application Request Routing + URL Rewrite) for RhodeCode running at 127.0.0.1:5000.

The Repository is reachable via "https://subdomain.domain.de".

At the repository summary, the Clone url points to: 
https://[username]@127.0.0.1:5000/SomeProject

At the client side, I can clone the repository when replacing the 
"127.0.0.1:5000" with "subdomain.domain.de".

For sure I would like that RhodeCode displays the Proxy url 
("subdomain.domain.de") instead of the 127.XXX...

I search the web up and down and the only thing I found, was that 
Apache has a "ProxyPreserveHost On" setting, which does the trick. However 
I didn't found anything like that for IIS.

Is there somewhere a setting within the "production.ini" where I can 
define the proxy url? 
Or does someone found the well hidden setting within the IIS?

Any help is much appreciated :-)

---

thanks for your answer! I already use the ARR and setup the reverse proxy, I can access RhodeCode via the proxy. However, it looks like that the HTTP_HOST value is not forwarded to paster.

Within the IIS, I setup the following server variables and set them within the reverse proxy rule:

```
<set name="HTTP_HOST" value="[subdomain.domain.de]" />
<set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER" value="[subdomain.domain.de]" />
<set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST" value="[subdomain.domain.de]" />
<set name="HTTP_X_HTTP_HOST" value="[subdomain.domain.de]" />
<set name="HTTP_X_URL_SCHEME" value="https" />
```

but that have no affect at all.

At the linked previously answer, he suggested to copy these variable values back to the HTTP_HOST (within tomcat, should be paster in my case). That looks a bit overkilled to me, in comparsion to a simple "ProxyPreserveHost On" within apache. I have the feeling that I missed something here.

Cheers,
Sörnt

Answer (score 2):

Itvan is correct, that will work.

Uncommenting the clone_uri will leave the default clone_uri. You can force the clone_uri to use your domain by having that line:

```
clone_uri = {scheme}://{user}{pass}[subdomain.domain.de]{path}
```

PS: Works on version 1.3.6

Comment: Once you got the rep, use comments to answer other answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

[I'm working on out reverse proxying over https for rhodecode with apache on centos6 right now.](http://mbrownnyc.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/install-rhodecode-and-redmine/)

For Apache, the [configuration noted by marcin of rhodecode fame](http://packages.python.org/RhodeCode/setup.html#apache-virtual-host-reverse-proxy-example) is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hg.myserver.com
    ServerAlias hg.myserver.com

    <Proxy *>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    #important !
    #Directive to properly generate url (clone url) for pylons
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    #rhodecode instance
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/

    #to enable https use line below
    #SetEnvIf X-Url-Scheme https HTTPS=1
</VirtualHost>
```

For the IIS equivilent of ProxyPreserveHost, see [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting), which was provided in [a previously answer by a MSFT MVP](https://serverfault.com/questions/128890/is-there-an-iis-7-application-request-routing-equivilent-of-apaches-proxypreser).

The http server is actually python paste's httpserver, so [referring to the python paste documentation for httpserver](http://pythonpaste.org/modules/httpserver.html?highlight=http#paste.httpserver) (`egg#Paste:http` is familiar right), there is no proxy configuration. You will have to [reverse proxy in IIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2010/04/02/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx) ([source](http://forums.iis.net/t/1156458.aspx))

I am unsure why marcin has opted to advise setting up the reverse proxy versus utilizing paste's httpserver support for https; but having IIS field the requests, and binding paste's httpserver to 127.0.0.1 is likely best choice.

Answer (score 1):

I've just installed RhodeCode 1.3.3 and got into this issue. You can edit this line in configuration file to make it work:

```
## overwrite schema of clone url
## available vars:
## scheme - http/https
## user - current user
## pass - password 
## netloc - network location
## path - usually repo_name

#clone_uri = {scheme}://{user}{pass}{netloc}{path}

clone_uri = {scheme}://{user}{pass}yourdomain.com{path}
```

Comment: Which part did you edit? These are commented out by default, aren't they?

Comment: @SimeonFitch Sorry it was a long time but since I have no email notification so I didn't see your question. I updated the answer to be clearer.